# Where is the Mouseover trigger for chords in Bostock's "Uber Rides by Neighborhood" Chord viz?

Tags: mobile, d3.js, tooltip, mouseover, chord-diagram

Folks-

I'm working on a d3.js chord diagram that is based on http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/ :

[image]

Line 88 clearly shows the mouseover event for the neighborhood "group" object.

Line 123-130 show how the title is concatenated for the chord.

However, there is no mouseover trigger to show/hide the .text associated with the nodes.

Is this an "automatic" feature of JS? Or is the behavior part of the d3.js script?

The reason I ask is that I need to replace the hover behavior with a click behavior, since it needs to be usable on the iPad.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Are you talking about the tooltips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tooltip is an automatic browser feature that is based on the `<title>` element inside a shape element.  In the chord diagram example, you can see `group.append("title")` at line 91 and `chord.append("title")` at line 123.

There is no automatic equivalent for touch devices that I know of.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I guess I'll have to see if I can add a mousedown or mouseup trigger and how that works from a UI perspective.

Comment: Remember that on touch devices it is touchstart and touchend instead of mousedown and mouseup.